# How should i remain on same page when i reload a page in flutter web using auto route ? Is there any other way to reload a page i flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, reload, auto-route

I want to reload a page in flutter web and want to remain on same the page how can i do it ?

I tried auto route package of flutter

```
`import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';

import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

import 'portal_router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Route')

class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {

  @override

  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [

        AutoRoute(
          page: LandingPageRoute.page,
          path: "/landing-page-route",
          initial: true,
        ),

        AutoRoute(page: MyDrawerRoute.page),

        AutoRoute(

page: LandingPageRoute.page,

),

      ];
}`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without additional info, you may want to use a StatefulWidget for the page and call `SetState()` whenever you want to refresh the page and rebuild the widget.